# Adding new DIMM slot in laptop by soldering

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr

I have laptop Acer Aspire One 722. Specification says that it has 2 DIMM slots, but when I opened it, I found it has only one, and there is a place for second one.  I'm just interested, could I add second one DIMM slot? Can I just solder a new one into that slot?

Comment: I haven't checked the specs, but are you sure that the "slot 1" RAM isn't simply soldered directly to the motherboard?

Comment: Can you add a photo of that? Are there already the holes where you could plug in the DIMM socket? And does the spec really say "2 DIMM with x GB max?

Comment: Have you looked under the laptop keyboard? Many manufacturers put one DIMM socket under the keyboard and the other on the underside (behind an access door).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer**: No (most likely)

**Long answer**: The connection from the northbridge chip to the ram slots consists of various supporting hardware (capacitors, resistors ect..). Most likely those components have been omitted as well.

I built computers for a company that used desktop motherboards which only had 2 of the 4 ram slots populated. It was very easy to see that resistors and capacitors around the empty ram slots were also missing.

If you try it, and have success, post your results.

Checkout these pictures from someone who asked the same question.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/294379-30-solder-memory-slot-acer-aspire-ao722